# Ember JS Enable dropdown only on element which was clicked

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am an Ember newbie and can't get my head around how to run events on specific elements populated via records on my ember model.

Here is my Template

```
{{#each user in model }}
  {{#each activecredit in user.activecredits}}
    <div class="col-lg-2 hive-credit-box active-credit">
        <div class="credit-brandname">
            {{activecredit.Brandname}}
        </div>
        <div class="credit-brand-image-container">

            <img src="http://localhost:3000/{{activecredit.Imglocation}}" class="credit-image"/>
        </div>

        <div class="hive-credit-percent"><img class="hive-filled-container" src="imgs/hivefilled9.png"/></div>
        <div class="hive-credit-dollars">$xx.xx</div>
        <div  {{bind-attr class=activecredit.Brandname}} {{action 'enableTrade'}}><img src="imgs/trade_button.png" class="credit-trade-button"  /></div>
        <div class="credit-brand-amount">
            xx%
        </div>

        <!-- Trade button click dropdown -->
       {{#if isSelected}}

        <div class="hivetrade">
            <div class="arrow_box">
                Hi there
            </div>
            <div class=""></div>
        </div>
        {{/if}}

    </div>
   {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
```

Now I want to show a drop down on each element on click of a button .

When I set the enableTrade action , all dropdowns of all the divs show up.

```
actions:{
  enableTrade:function(){
      this.set('isSelected',true);
  }
}
```

How do I enable only the dropdown in the particular div that was created.

I suppose I need to bind certain attributes to each div,but how do I access which div was clicked in my controller?

Any help would be appreciated .
Thanks

Comment: What version of ember are you using? I'm going to post my answer to reflect the latest code features and standards, but will add comments as needed for you if you are on an old version.

Comment: I am using Ember CLI v1.11.0

Comment: you mean ember 1.11.0? ember-cli's latest is 0.2.7 :)  Posting answer, the conventions shown all work in 1.11.0+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass params through the action helper, and use them to set `isSelected` on the appropriate item.

```
{{#each model as |user| }}
  {{#each user.activeCredits as |activeCredit|}}
     <button {{action 'enableTrade' activeCredit}}>Enable Trade</button>

     {{#if activeCredit.isSelected}}
       <div class="hivetrade">Hello World</div>
     {{/if}}

  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

To handle it:

```
actions:{
  enableTrade:function(credit) {
    credit.set('isSelected',true);
  }
}
```

If you need to allow only one credit to be selected at a time, your controller and action could be modified like this:

```
selectedCredit: null,
actions:{
  enableTrade:function(credit) {

    // unselect the previously selected credit
    if (this.get('selectedCredit')) {
      this.set('selectedCredit.isSelected', false);
    }

    // select, and cache the selection choice
    credit.set('isSelected',true);
    this.set('selectedCredit', credit);
  }
}
```

Comment: Also note, you may want to use a component for this, similar to the answer I give here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31096550/1883464

Comment: Worked like a charm,thanks.
Didn't know we could pass parameters to Ember controllers :)

Comment: One more noobie question : How do I hide all dropdowns when I click outside the div?